# Sort by day, ignoring hours and minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem for you. I would like to sort by day, but if several with different times are sorted on the day, it separates them. How do I get it out that he only shows all day by day

My date field looks like this

```
Datum                         weight
2022-12-09 07:12:49.000       2150
2022-12-09 08:15:49.000       1250
```

My query

```
Select FORMAT(Datum, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'de-DE') as Datum, SUM(weight)
FROM [Produktionsdaten].[dbo].[produktionedelstahl]
WHERE Anlage IN ('Bonak 2')
  AND YEAR(Datum)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND MONTH(Datum)=MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
group BY (Datum)
```

I want the day to be summarized

```
Datum           weight
12-09-2022      3400
```

Comment: dstum isnt a referable object in the scope you have it in. youd have to wrap your query in a sub query if you want to refer to it like that or just copy and paste the format into the order by

Comment: Why not just use date boundaries in the `WHERE`? What you have isn't SARGable, and would perform quite poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were nearly there - just change the last line

```
Select FORMAT(Datum, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'de-DE') as Datum, SUM(weight)
FROM [Produktionsdaten].[dbo].[produktionedelstahl]
WHERE Anlage IN ('Bonak 2')
  AND YEAR(Datum)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND MONTH(Datum)=MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
group BY FORMAT(Datum, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'de-DE')
```

Comment: Yes thats works. I so stupid :-)

Answer (score 0):

could you try to perform the SELECT in this way.

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATE(Datum), 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'de-DE') AS Datum, SUM(weight)
FROM [Produktionsdaten].[dbo].[produktionedelstahl]
WHERE Anlage IN ('Bonak 2')
AND YEAR(Datum)=YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
AND MONTH(Datum)=MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY DATE(Datum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by casting the DATETIME to a DATE and going from there.

```sql
SELECT CAST(Datum AS DATE) AS Datum, SUM(Weight) AS Weight
FROM [Produktionsdaten].[dbo].[produktionedelstahl]
GROUP BY CAST(Datum AS DATE)
```

Here is a very small sample script to demonstrate that this works:

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Datum DATETIME, Weight INT);
INSERT INTO @Data(Datum, Weight) VALUES ('2022-12-09 07:12:49.000', 2150), ('2022-12-09 08:15:49.000', 1250);

SELECT CAST(Datum AS DATE) AS Datum, SUM(Weight) AS Weight
FROM @Data 
GROUP BY CAST(Datum AS DATE)
```

Output:

| Datum | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-09 | 3400 |